# Why FDI stock in the same year is different in the same reports?

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, investment, open-economy-macro, balance-of-payments

From [World Investment Report 2003](http://unctad.org/en/docs/wir2003light_en.pdf), in 2000, the US has **12.4%** GDP as FDI inward stock and **13.2%** GDP as FDI outward stock. These numbers are equivalent to **1274720** million USD, and **1356960** million USD. With GDP US in 2003 as **10.28** billion USD.

From [World Investment Report 2007](http://unctad.org/en/docs/wir2007_en.pdf), in 2000, the shares above are **12.8** and **13.4**, respectively.

From [World Investment Report 2017](http://unctad.org/en/PublicationsLibrary/wir2017_en.pdf), however, in 2000, the US has **2783235** million USD as FDI inward stocks, and **2694014** million USD as FDI outward stock. If we measure in percentage as above, we would have **27%** and **26%** equivalently.

Why are the numbers are so different? Do I forget something like the price levels or so?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: These will be changes in information provided by the US Government to UNCTAD: compare the US data ($1,214,254-1,256,867-2,783,235$ and $1,293,431-1,316,247-2,694,014$ million dollars) with the comparable Austrian numbers in the same tables ($30,431-30,431-31,165$ and $24,820-24,821-24,821$) to see they do not have to change.  My guess is that small changes may be driven by new information while large changes may be associated with domestic methodology and definitional issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In note 1 of the [World Investment Report 2017](http://unctad.org/en/PublicationsLibrary/wir2017_en.pdf) (page 39), it is mentioned that

> FDI data may differ from one WIR issue to another as data are
>   continually revised, updated and corrected by the responsible
>   authorities, such as central banks and statistical offices, that
>   provide FDI data to UNCTAD.

The last figures are the most accurate ones.